# Remove symbolic link

Tags: symlink

I have the following situation:

```
[ORACLE]/u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network> ll
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 36 May 11  2016 admin -> /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin
[ORACLE]/u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network> cd  /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin
-bash: cd: /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I am not sure who or why the symbolic link was created, but I would like to remove it without removing the contents of the admin folder.  Is it just rm admin or is there a different command?

Answer (score 3):

It is just `rm admin`, assuming there is no alias for `rm` defined. You could do `/bin/rm -i admin`, if you are nervous - the `-i` option will explicitly ask `rm: remove symbolic link 'admin'?`.

Just make sure you don't use <kbd>Tab</kbd> which might get you a `/` after admin, (although you would still need `-rf` to make that cause problems)

Comment: You might want to add mention of what the problem is - likely that there is a recursive tree of links going on.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the synonym of `rm`: `unlink admin` in your case.

B.T.W, from your console output

> -bash: cd: /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin: Too many levels of symbolic links

you're creating a cyclic symbolic link, which in your case using `cd /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin`, you're actually `cd <symlink>` recursively. You probably want to create the symlink in another directory other than `/u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/`, e.g. `sudo ln -sf /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin /tmp/admin`.

Comment: I looked up the history commands and see this:                                       220  su - oracle
  221  cd /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/
  222  ll
  223  mv admin admin.orig
  224  ln -s /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.2/network/admin .                                 Does the rm admin still apply in this situation if the folder is being linked to itself?

Comment: yes, just `rm` it will be fine, and relink it using `ln -s [source] [target]`(*target* should be in different folder or at least with different name to *source*)